# Getting [iMac.domain_not_set.invalid ~] in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open up my terminal I now get:

```
[iMac.domain_not_set.invalid ~ 501]$
```

In my .bash_profile it says:

```
export PS1='[\H \W \!]\$ '
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What is `hostname` returning?

Comment: it returns `iMac.domain_not_set.invalid`

Comment: This sounds a lot like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal), except in this case the DNS server is supposed to be configured with a valid domain, but isn't, so it's using an error message as the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Your hostname is not set correctly. This could be because of the information you set in Sharing in System Preferences, or because the DHCP server gave your system an incorrect hostname to use.

To fix this, change your hostname in Sharing, or in case of a DHCP issue, check the DHCP server configuration.

Comment: So what does the OP need to do this fix this?